# Updating User.UserAttributes on AWS Pinpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

I cannot seem to update pre-existing UserAttributes on a user "73". I am not sure if this behaviour is to be expected.

```java
Map<String, List<String>> userAttributes = new HashMap<>();
userAttributes.put("Inference", Arrays.asList("NEGATIVE"));
userAttributes.put("Gender", Arrays.asList("M"));
userAttributes.put("ChannelPreference", Arrays.asList("EMAIL"));
userAttributes.put("TwitterHandle", Arrays.asList("Nutter"));
userAttributes.put("Age", Arrays.asList("435"));

EndpointUser endpointUser = new EndpointUser().withUserId("73");
endpointUser.setUserAttributes(userAttributes);

EndpointRequest endpointRequest = new EndpointRequest().withUser(endpointUser);

UpdateEndpointResult updateEndpointResult = pinpoint.updateEndpoint(new UpdateEndpointRequest()
    .withEndpointRequest(endpointRequest).withApplicationId("380c3902d4ds47bfb6f9c6749c6dc8bf").withEndpointId("a1fiy2gy+eghmsadj1vqew6+aa"));

System.out.println(updateEndpointResult.getMessageBody());
```

Answer (score 0):

@David.Webster,

You can update user-attributes of Amazon Pinpoint endpoint using the below Java code snippet which I have tested to be working :

```java
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        // Try to update the endpoint.
        try {

            System.out.println("===============================================");

            System.out.println("Getting Started with Amazon Pinpoint"
                    +"using the AWS SDK for Java...");
            System.out.println("===============================================\n");


            // Initializes the Amazon Pinpoint client.
            AmazonPinpoint pinpointClient = AmazonPinpointClientBuilder.standard()
            .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();


            // Creates a new user definition.
            EndpointUser jackchan = new EndpointUser().withUserId("73");

            // Assigns custom user attributes.
            jackchan.addUserAttributesEntry("name", Arrays.asList("Jack", "Chan"));
            jackchan.addUserAttributesEntry("Inference", Arrays.asList("NEGATIVE"));
            jackchan.addUserAttributesEntry("ChannelPreference", Arrays.asList("EMAIL"));
            jackchan.addUserAttributesEntry("TwitterHandle", Arrays.asList("Nutter"));
            jackchan.addUserAttributesEntry("gender", Collections.singletonList("M"));
            jackchan.addUserAttributesEntry("age", Collections.singletonList("435"));

            // Adds the user definition to the EndpointRequest that is passed to the Amazon Pinpoint client.
            EndpointRequest jackchanIphone = new EndpointRequest()
                    .withUser(jackchan);

            // Updates the specified endpoint with Amazon Pinpoint.
            UpdateEndpointResult result = pinpointClient.updateEndpoint(new UpdateEndpointRequest()
                    .withEndpointRequest(jackchanIphone)
                    .withApplicationId("4fd13a407f274f10b4ec06cbc71738bd")
                    .withEndpointId("095A8688-7D79-43CE-BDCE-7DF713332BC3"));

            System.out.format("Update endpoint result: %s\n", result.getMessageBody().getMessage());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("EndpointUpdate Failed");
            System.err.println("Error message: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps